# How to make onTap only respond on Actual Text not whole ListTile width

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

### Illustrations

I have the following problem:

[image: ListTile]

The `title` and `subtitle` components of [`ListTile`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html) expand fully even when there only is text in some smaller area.
Usually, this is not a problem as you could just color the background of the `title` the same as the `ListTie`.

However, I have a problem when trying to get an `onTap` event working on a **`Row`** in `title` or `subtitle`:

[image: ListTile onTap]

As you can see, I have a `Row` in the `title` component with an `Icon` and a `Text`. That works fine, however, trying to add an `onTap` to this `title` will produce unwanted behavior.
I **only** want the `onTap` to trigger when I **actually tap the text or icon** and not when I tap *somewhere else to the right*. I am clueless how I would constrain the width of the `title` to the width of the text plus icon. It seems like nothing works. What is going on here?

### Code

I [created a Gist](https://gist.github.com/creativecreatorormaybenot/cf45daddb43280cf4038f9a5774016b8) with the source code (minimal reproducible example) for *both illustrations*. This should help to give you an idea of the setup.

How do I only trigger `onTap` when the actual children of the `Row` are tapped and not the whole `title` area that apparently expands no matter what I do?

### Notes

I could probably just add an `InkWell` to both the `Text` and the `Icon` individually, however, that is not at all what I want because I want a splash (`InkWell`'s splash) to cover the title and icon together and they should not be visually seperated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try this code it works for me

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
            child: ListTile(
              dense: true,
              leading: Material(child: const Text('leading')),
              title: Material(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {},
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.format_align_left),
                          Text(
                            'title',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                      Container(
                        height: 0.0,
                      ),

//                    Expanded(child: Container(
//                      height: 10.0,
//                    ),)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              subtitle: Material(child: const Text('subtitle')),
              trailing: Material(child: const Text('trailing')),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for that. I thought that I tried it before, this is hilarious.

Comment: No worries , it happens :)

Comment: Please note that there are two nested rows in the code , not sure if you mean that .

Answer (score 1):

Use `FlatButton.icon` instead of using  `InkWell` and `Row`.

`FlatButton.icon` solves your mentioned problem and serves both of your purpose to have splash effect and a Title with Icon. It reduces your code too. See below for example

```
title: Align(
     alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
     heightFactor: 1.0,
     child: FlatButton.icon(
         splashColor: Colors.white,
         onPressed: () {},
         icon: Icon(Icons.format_align_left),
         label: Text('title'))),
```

---

Full code

```
main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.greenAccent,
            child: ListTile(
              dense: true,
              leading: Material(child: const Text('leading')),
              title: Material(
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    heightFactor: 1.0,
                    child: FlatButton.icon(
                        splashColor: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(Icons.format_align_left),
                        label: Text('title'))),
              ),
              subtitle: Material(child: const Text('subtitle')),
              trailing: Material(child: const Text('trailing')),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Well, I do not want to use `FlatButton.icon`. I only used an icon plus text for the example.

Comment: I needed to illustrate the issue. It is about a `Row` expanding in `ListView`'s `title`.